# Is it possible to rename a "by" grouping variable in data.table in R en passant?

Tags: r, data.table

I have noticed in `data.table` when aggregating values using the `by` option, the grouping variable takes its natural order in the dataset, akin to SQL I believe. So if 2 precedes 1 in the data, the ordering of the output has the aggregate level 2 preceding 1. In most cases, I don't want this. I noticed one can call `sort` on the `by` variable, but the output column label is now `sort`. Is it possible to name it by its previous value (or something completely different?) example:

```
mydt <- data.table(nums=1:5, lets=letters[5:1])
mydt[, .(is2=nums==2), by=sort(lets)]
```

gives

```
   sort is2
1:    a   F
2:    b   T
3:    c   F
4:    d   F
5:    e   F
```

but I want:

```
   lets is2
1:    a   F
2:    b   T
3:    c   F
4:    d   F
5:    e   F
```

Comment: EDIT... apparently, calling `by=sort(x)` gives very unpredictable behavior. I've no idea what's actually happening here. Does anyone have insight?

Comment: `keyby=` you mean? Or `by=.(name = var)`?

Comment: @Frank I think I mean the latter. I will have to do considerably more sleuthing to understand why I get the numerical differences I'm having. I think it must sort the "by" variable in isolation, then aggregate the rest of the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is titled *Is it possible to rename a “by” grouping variable in data.table in R en passant?* but the actual problem is how to sort the result of an aggregation by the grouping variables. So, there are two questions in one.

#### Is it possible to rename a “by” grouping variable in data.table in R en passant?

Yes, it is, e.g.,

```
mydt[, .(is2 = nums == 2), by = .(lets = paste(lets, toupper(lets), sep = "-"))]
```

> ```
>    lets   is2
> 1:  e-E FALSE
> 2:  d-D  TRUE
> 3:  c-C FALSE
> 4:  b-B FALSE
> 5:  a-A FALSE
> ```

For illustration, a completely different function is used.

#### How to sort the result of an aggregation by the grouping variables?

The simplest way is to use `keyby =` as already mentioned by [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448420/is-it-possible-to-rename-a-by-grouping-variable-in-data-table-in-r-en-passant#comment83891671_48448420).

```
mydt[, .(is2 = nums == 2), keyby = lets]
```

> ```
>    lets   is2
> 1:    a FALSE
> 2:    b FALSE
> 3:    c FALSE
> 4:    d  TRUE
> 5:    e FALSE
> ```

`help("data.table")` says

> Same as `by`, but with an additional `setkey()` run on the `by` columns of
>   the result, for convenience. It is common practice to use 'keyby='
>   routinely when you wish the result to be sorted.

Alternatively, the result can be ordered afterwards:

```
mydt[, .(is2 = nums == 2), by = lets][order(lets)]
```

> ```
>    lets   is2
> 1:    a FALSE
> 2:    b FALSE
> 3:    c FALSE
> 4:    d  TRUE
> 5:    e FALSE
> ```